# Как в C++ создать процесс с именем Load.txt?

Tags: c++, winapi

Мне нужно создать процесс с именем Load.txt (ну или любым другим). Должен быть только процесс, без окон и тд

Comment: А что вы понимаете под *именем* процесса?

Comment: @Harry в диспетчере задач "procname.расширение"

Comment: Типа этого? https://ibb.co/tqh5BrV

Comment: @Harry именно это

Comment: Создаете консольное приложение `Load.txt.exe`, запускаете и радуетесь жизни :)